# Quartz.Net - update/delete jobs/triggers

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz to pull latest tasks (from another source), it then adds it in as a job, creates triggers etc per each task. - Easy.

However, sometimes tasks change (therefore they already exist). Therefore I would like to change its (lets say to keep it simple `Description`. Code below updates specific task's description with given date.

```
private static void SetLastPull(DateTime lastPullDateTime)
{
  var lastpull = sched.GetJobDetail("db_pull", "Settings");

  if(lastpull != null)
  {
    lastpull.Description = lastPullDateTime.ToString();
  }
  else
  {
    var newLastPull = new JobDetail("db_pull", "Settings", typeof(IJob));
    newLastPull.Description = lastPullDateTime.ToString();
    var newLastPullTrigger = new CronTrigger("db_pull", "Settings", "0 0 0 * 12 ? 2099");
    sched.ScheduleJob(newLastPull, newLastPullTrigger);
  }
}
```

I'm assuming after I do `lastpull.Description = lastPullDateTime.ToString();` I should call something to save changes to database. **Is there a way to do it in Quartz or do I have to go to using other means and update it?**

Comment: Worked it out. I had to go `sched.AddJob(lastpull, true)`. Very counter intuitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change (update) a job once it has been scheduled. You can only re-schedule it (with any changes you might want to make) or delete it and create a new one.